# Попап при воспроизведении в youtube

Tags: fancybox, popup, youtube

Кто сталкивался со скриптом - при воспроизведении youtube-видео производится его остановка и всплывает попап по типу:

[image]

Пример такой:

```
<div class="videoScript">
    <script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script><br />
    <script>
        var player;function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){player=new YT.Player("player",{height:"450",width:"800",playerVars:{'start':0,'end':115,'theme':'light','rel': 0},videoId:"s-zVVSWB94o",events:{onStateChange:onPlayerStateChange}})}function onPlayerStateChange(a){if(a.data===0){videoEnded();}};
    </script>
</div>
```

В момент, когда `'end':115`, вылетает попап (fancybox).

Как реализовать скрипт, который в этот момент запустит попап?